# Get a list of files to array using filters

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get the list of files from a directory using array with filters. But only the last file gets into the array.

```
filter_list=("windows" "linux" "test")
declare -a file_list
for z in "${filter_list[@]}"; do
 file_list=(`ls /home/user/*$z* | xargs -n 1 basename`)
done
```

How can I get all files that fit the filter criteria?

Thanks

Comment: You are reassigning you file_list variable at each loop. Use the "+=" operator instead of just "=".

Comment: That worked, thanks Andre!